# Найти самый часто встречаемый цвет и заменить его на другой заданный цвет LIBPNG

Tags: c, изображения, libpng

Требуется найти самый часто встречаемый цвет и заменить его на другой заданный цвет. Нужно написать программу на c используя библиотеку libpng. Функции для чтения и сохранения картинки у меня есть. Я знаю как получить характеристики цвета каждого пикселя в виде значения компонент R, G, B, A (от 0 до 255 каждая). Есть мысль загнать цвета всех пикселей в массив и как-то его отсортировать, чтобы узнать самый часто встречаемый цвет, но я пока не придумал как это сделать.

Comment: Ну, формально у вас цвет - это 4 байта, так что если делать просто массив - он теоретически может быть более 4 миллиардов значений, а если это массив `int`ов - то нужно 16 Гбайт памяти. Так что как минимум лучше использовать один из алгоритмов для разреженных массивов.

Comment: Картинка - это уже и есть готовый массив. И алгоритм для сортировке есть в стандартной библиотеке. В чем затруднение - непонятно.

Comment: @user7860670 смотри: у меня есть массив [R1, G1, B1, A1, R2, G2, B2, A2, ... Rn, Gn, Bn, An], где Ri, Gi, Bi, Ai - компоненты каждого пикселя. И как мне его отсортировать, чтобы не разорвать пиксели?

Comment: Группами по 4 компонента.

Comment: @user7860670 можешь объяснить как это сделать (можно псевдокодом)? Просто я не знаю как через qsort это можно реализовать, а других функций сортировки не знаю.

Comment: Ну тогда заводите отдельный вопрос "как использовать qsort "

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
int *arr = malloc(100000*sizeof(int));
int n = 0; 
int buf = 100000;
int f = 0; int h = 0;
for (y = 0; y < image->height; y++) {
    png_byte *row = image->row_pointers[y];
    for (x = 0; x < image->width; x++) {
        png_byte *ptr = &(row[x * 4]);

        if((buf - 500) == n){
            buf += 1000;
            arr = realloc(arr, buf*sizeof(int));
        }

        arr[n] = ptr[0]*1000000+ptr[1]*1000+ptr[2];
        n++;
    }
}

printf("n = %d\n", n);

qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), cmp);

int max_num = arr[0]; int max_count = 1; int max_n2 = - 1; int max_c2 = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){ 

    if(arr[i] == arr[i - 1]){
        if(arr[i] == max_num) 
            max_count++; 
        if(arr[i] == max_n2)
            max_c2++;
    }
    if(arr[i] != arr[i - 1]){
        max_n2 = arr[i];
        max_c2 = 1;
    }
    if(max_c2 > max_count){
        max_num = max_n2;
        max_count = max_c2;
    }
}

printf("max_num = %d; max_count = %d\n", max_num, max_count);
int max_r; int max_g; int max_b;
max_r = max_num/1000000;
max_g = (max_num - max_r*1000000)/1000;
max_b = max_num - max_r*1000000 - max_g*1000;

for (y = 0; y < image->height; y++) {
    png_byte *row = image->row_pointers[y];
    for (x = 0; x < image->width; x++) {
        png_byte *ptr = &(row[x * 4]);

        if(ptr[0] == max_r && ptr[1] == max_g && ptr[2] == max_b){
            if(rp_color == 1){
                ptr[0] = 0; ptr[1] = 0; ptr[2] = 0;
            }
            if(rp_color == 2){
                ptr[0] = 255; ptr[1] = 0; ptr[2] = 0;
            }
            if(rp_color == 3){
                ptr[0] = 0; ptr[1] = 0; ptr[2] = 255;
            }
            if(rp_color == 4){
                ptr[0] = 0; ptr[1] = 255; ptr[2] = 0;
            }
            if(rp_color == 5){
                ptr[0] = 255; ptr[1] = 255; ptr[2] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Вспомогательные определения (для ясности)
typedef uint8_t* ImgPtr;
ImgPtr cloneImage(ImgPtr img, uint16_t width, uint16_t height, uint8_t nComponents);
void deleteImage(ImgPtr img);

int colorComparePredicate(const void* first, const void* second) {
    // Разность цветов (без альфы)
    return (*((const uint32_t*)first) & 0x00FFFFFF) - (*((const uint32_t*)second) & 0x00FFFFFF);
}

uint32_t getFrequentColor(ImgPtr img, uint16_t width, uint16_t height, uint8_t nComponents) {  
    // Рассматриваемый цвет и его количество  
    uint32_t currentColor = -1;
    uint32_t currentColorCount = 0;

    // Цвет самой длинной цепочки и его количество
    uint32_t frequentColor = -1;
    uint32_t frequentColorCount = 0;

    // Клон изображения для сортировки
    ImgPtr imgCopy = cloneImage(img, width, height, nComponents);
    // Сортировка цветов в "цепочки"(последовательности одинаковых цветов)
    qsort((void*)imgCopy, width * height, nComponents, colorComparePredicate);

    ImgPtr imgIterator = imgCopy;
    ImgPtr end = imgCopy + width * height * nComponents;

    // Определяем, какого цвета больше всего (Обойдя все цепочки цветов)
    while( imgIterator < end ) {
        // Получаем значение цвета (без альфы)
        uint32_t color = (*((uint32_t*)imgIterator) & 0x00FFFFFF);

        // Проверка на смену цвета (новая цепочка)
        if ( color != currentColor ) {
            if ( currentColorCount > frequentColorCount ) {
                frequentColor = currentColor;
                frequentColorCount = currentColorCount;
            }

            currentColor = color;
            currentColorCount = 0;
        }

        ++currentColorCount;
        imgIterator += nComponents;
    }
    if ( currentColorCount > frequentColorCount ) {
        frequentColor = currentColor;
        frequentColorCount = currentColorCount;
    }

    deleteImage(imgCopy);

    return frequentColor;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь дать комментарии к вашему коду